# Common condition for running multiple test?

Tags: java, junit, conditional-statements

I have a couple of tests that can run only if one condition met (media server is up and operational). How should I code this condition so that jUnit don't run rests if server is down and inform me that the reason is not met?

**UPDATE**

May be I can describe some test dependency?

The goal is to see that not tests failed, but condition does not met. If I code `setUp` or something I will just see that multiple tests are failed, without any explanation. If I had one test which tests condition itself and all other tests execute only if this one suceeded, then the problem would evident...

Comment: You could add this as part of your `setUp()` code.

Comment: Which version of JUnit are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You could add this as part of your `setUp()` code. If `setUp()` throws an exception, the test isn't run. Of course, the TestRunner usually iterates through each method that starts with `test` and runs `setUp()` for each one, so this isn't a terribly efficient solution.

Comment: You could still run the check once and cache the result.

Comment: Or he could do it in a method with the `@BeforeClass` annotation, assuming he's using JUnit 4, then check the result in the `@Before` method.